# Create a region calculation in the cube SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I have a hierarchy of customers which include details of Country,City, Postal code with customer key. All I want to do is to group these countries according to their territories, Europe - North America - South America, to show the total sales for each one. How do I achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could total the data by Country (the highest level you currently have under ALL), and then externally group the results by Region (e.g. in Excel with a lookup mapping Countries to their Region).

There's no other sensible way to add an extra hierarchy level (which is what your Territory is) to cube data on the fly.  The best way is to design the Region into the hierarchy as a level: meaning adding a Region column to the dimension source data, populating it, adding a Region attribute to the dimension, and putting this Region attribute into the hierarchy, below ALL and above Country.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your reply. I already did as you described by creating a calculated member for each region within the hierarchy of the country. I then summed the total sales value for each region which showed right in the bottom of the listed countries. But I wanted to create it as a dynamic script which splits these countries into three territories to show the total sales for each one seperately

Comment: I didn't realise you'd already used the calculated member method.  That's a good solution if you have no ability to change the design of the dimension.  I don't understand what you mean by a "dynamic script", though: how does your calculated-member solution not meet your requirement?

Comment: Dynamic Script: is when the calculated member work for different calculations i.e. total costs, margin, etc.. I thought I could create three different regions each has different set of countries. Then I could use these regions to show the sums of total sales or profit made for example!

Comment: I am using the reporting services to show a graph of the three territories based on the fiscal and the calendar dates. However, at the moment I am only able to show the all countries rather than the identified territories ! :(

Comment: I think you can create named sets in the cube's CALCULATE MDX-script.  Not that I ever have.  You could then create three calculated measures, each one totalling only over its region (set of countries).  You'd have to create 3 more calcd measures for each underlying measure you want to work on.  I'd recommend changing the dimension design, though, as this approach can soon become very complicated and hard to maintain.

Comment: Oh, it sounds complicated enough! I rather keep it on the calculated member! Can I eliminate the territories attributes only from showing in the report. I mean I can show a summary of sales for all countries and include the territories to be a subreport - as a graph - within the main report!